# Did Hamilton really send Burr an "itemised list of thirty years of disagreements"?

Tags: american-revolution, founding-fathers

In the production of Hamilton, during the song "Your Obedient Servant", which imagines the conversation between Aaron Burr and Hamilton shortly before their duel, the following exchange happens:

> [HAMILTON]
>
> I am not the reason no one trusts you
>
> No one knows what you believe
>
> I will not equivocate on my opinion
>
> I have always worn it on my sleeve
>
> Even if I said what you think I said
>
> You would need to cite a more specific grievance
>
> **Here’s an itemized list of thirty years of disagreements**
>
> [BURR]
>
> Sweet Jesus

Is this just a throwaway line from the show, or did Hamilton really write such a list?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: "A line from the song, "Here's an itemized list of 30 years of disagreements", is an homage to Leslie Knope from Parks & Recreation." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Obedient_Servant_(song)),  and "The line "An itemized list of 30 years of disagreements" is not a reference to any real document, rather a reference to Parks and Recreation, in which Leslie Knope says the same line." [Duel Correspondence](https://hamiltonmusical.fandom.com/wiki/Burr-Hamilton_Duel_Correspondence)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: The question then becomes: "What (possibly) inspired the line in *Parks and Recreation*? Could it even have been Burr and hamilton?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, that question would (a) need to be supported by prior reserch and (b) probably be more in scope for the TV/Media stack exchange or a current event SE.  The methods and sources used to answer that question would be arguably distinct from historical sources and methods (history rarely gets to interview the author directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards their infamous duel the website [Founders Online](https://founders.archives.gov/) lists [Correspondence authored by Hamilton](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22&s=1111211111&r=1)

9. [From Alexander Hamilton to Aaron Burr, 20 June 1804 (Hamilton Papers)](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22&s=1111311111&r=9)
10. [From Alexander Hamilton to Aaron Burr, 22 June 1804 (Hamilton Papers)](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22&s=1111311111&r=10)

and [Correspondence authored by Burr](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22&s=1111211111&r=1):

4. [To Alexander Hamilton from Aaron Burr, 18 June 1804 (Hamilton Papers)](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22&s=1111311111&r=4)
5. To Alexander Hamilton from Aaron Burr, 21 June 1804 (Hamilton Papers)
6. [To Alexander Hamilton from Aaron Burr, 22 June 1804 (Hamilton Papers)](https://founders.archives.gov/?q=Correspondent%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22%20Correspondent%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22%20Author%3A%22Burr%2C%20Aaron%22&s=1111311111&r=6)

In his response of June 20, 1804 (no. 9 above), Hamilton writes:

> Repeating, that I cannot reconcile it with propriety to make the acknowlegement, or denial, you desire—I will add, that I deem it inadmissible, on principle, to consent to be interrogated as to the justness of the inferences, which may be drawn by others, from whatever I may have said of a political opponent in the course of a fifteen years competition. If there were no other objection to it, this is sufficient, that it would tend to expose my sincerity and delicacy to injurious imputations from every person, who may at any time have conceived the import of my expressions differently from what I may then have intended, or may afterwards recollect.

in which I note particularly "*... from whatever I may have said of a political opponent in the course of a fifteen years competition.*"

This reference seems close enough to be the origin of the phrase inquired on: "*Here’s an itemized list of thirty years of disagreements*". That seems to have  wound its way from Hamilton and Burr, to Leslie Knope in Parks & Recreation, and back again to Hamilton and Burr, with a little embellishment at each step.

Comment: that's interesting! What happened with Parks & Recreation?